# Modify github history

Tags: git, git-commit

I apologize in advance for asking this question as it has been asked a million times already.

I need to modify the git history of my project,
the commit history currently looks like this:

```
[E] <- [D] <- [C] <- [B] <- [A]
```

Where:
A: Added some code,
B: Added some code & added some data,
C: Restructured project,
D: Removed all data,
E: Added some code

The problem was that at commit C our project group was notified that data had to be stored locally and not publicly on git. I am not very experienced with git so the first thing I did was to remove the data. But that did not do much since the data could still be accessed in history. How do I fix the problem so that the history looks like this:

```
[E] <- [C] <- [B] <- [A]
```

Where:
A: Added some code,
B: Added some code,
C: Restructured project (Without any references to data)
E: Added some code

Comment: Note that any answer you get will require a force push, which will in turn require everyone who has this repo on their local machines to do some stuff as well to remove commit D.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to remove specific commit if from history

git rebase --onto commit-id  commit-id HEAD

You can use below command to remove commit "D" from history

git rebase --onto D  E HEAD

Comment: have you tried git commit --amend ? It allows you to edit commit.

Comment: I believe it should be `git rebase --onto E D HEAD`. Also, this requires a force push.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with these commands:

```
# Rebase from C commit in interactive mode...
git rebase -i C

# Then remove the D commit line in the editor, save and quit.
# You can edit commit messages by using "edit" option for
# concerned commits.
# Resolve conflicts if needed and finish rebasing.
```

OR (without commit message editing):

```
# Rebase from C: Pick E history but exclude D history
git rebase --onto C D E
```

Then you will have to push force the modification (with all troubles that it can lead to...).

```
# --force-with-lease means:
# "If anybody already pushed after the last known origin/<branch> sha1,
# The push force command will be aborted (avoids to loose newers pushes
# from your friends...).
git push --force-with-lease origin <branch>
```